# Can wordpress users check GMAIL (G Suite) inbox & send email from their membership account on WordPress?

Tags: email

I have a membership based website.

I also provide each member with their own Google Gmail via G Suite.

How can I make it so they can visit their dashboard or a page on my website to access their gmail emails and send emails out? Can this be done via API?

In short, i'd like to keep them on the site rather then have them leave to check emails.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a pretty big task, i don't think an answer here would be able to do what you want, purely from length restrictions alone. I don't believe there's a way to "embed" GMail in another site, but if there was it wouldn't be a WP question, not without building a massive amount of code

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make it so they can visit their dashboard or a page on my website to access their gmail emails and send emails out? Can this be done via API?
>
> In short, i'd like to keep them on the site rather then have them leave to check emails.

**Out of the box, no**. There are plugins that try to implement mail clients, such as WP SimpleMail, but I cannot guarantee that it will work, or that it will work well.

Building this yourself would be a **massive** piece of work, and easily several months of development work, if not a year

Keep in mind that the Google APIs are offtopic here, as are plugin recommendations

Your options are:

- send them to gmail
- test and install plugins that implement basic email clients and hope they work well
- spend 6 months building your own email client in PHP from scratch